# <body></body> tags are being inserted into the head of my document from jQueryMobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have just started getting a ***very strange*** error when using jQueryMobile for my mobile website/app

---

**edit** *i am adding a picture, probably a lot easier to understand the question*

[image: WTF?!?!?!?!]

---

**edit2** *i have found the issue. still curious as to why this is the way it is*
*if you wish to see the original post please read the edits*

So in my ***master.js*** file I had the following code

```
Object.prototype.hasAttr = function(attr) {
    var _attr;
    if(this.attr) {
        _attr = this.attr(attr);
    } else {
        _attr = this.getAttribute(attr);
    }
    return (typeof _attr !== "undefined" && _attr !== false && _attr !== null);
};
```

If I remove the code everything works! I have also run the code through jsLint and it does not contain errors. 
I've looked in the docs and the jQueryMobile framework does not have a function called `hasAttr` so where is the conflict?

---

***PLEASE NOTE: THIS FUNCTION IS NEVER ACTUALLY RUN! JUST INCLUDING IT BREAKS THINGS***

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. What script code?

Comment: My bad, I was fooled by the call to `bind()`. Sorry for that comment.

Comment: can you just remove the extra body tags with jquery? $("body").first().remove();

Comment: what **`framework`** does you believe is doing this?

Comment: @Evan, I would rather know ***why*** it is there to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Object.prototype.hasAttr = function(attr) {
    var _attr;
    if(this.attr) {
        _attr = this.attr(attr);
    } else {
        _attr = this.getAttribute(attr);
    }
    return (typeof _attr !== "undefined" && _attr !== false && _attr !== null);
};
```

conflicting code was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see the problem.  You are mixing and matching Jquery with prototype here. I think the function getAttribute is the problem, because that is not a jquery function and yet it is trying to act on a jquery object here

Comment: thats why I check for `if(this.attr)`, read my last update. This function is no longer required due to my new realization of using `dataset` however the question is still valid. Why would that code being included cause such an error.